# Reuse methods in multiple Rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Beginner ruby/rails question here. I have a method That I am currently using  in my "User" model.

`def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end`

I want to reuse the same method in a different model say my Account model.

Where is a good place to put code like this to be shared between models? 
Also, in order to get the calling class would I just use "self.class"?

Thanks

Comment: Concerns would be the rails convention for where to put something like this if you're using rails 4.  `self.class` should work fine

Answer (score 10):

Rails 4 `concerns` are here to do this job. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

`app/models/user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TokenGenerator

  def foo
    $stderr.puts self.class.generate_token("bar")
  end
end
```

`app/models/account.rb`:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TokenGenerator

  class << self
    def bar
      return generate_token("foo")
    end
  end
end
```

`app/models/concerns/token_generator.rb`

```
module TokenGenerator
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def generate_token(c)
      return "some_thing"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I assume if I wanted to call this in a before_ i would just use: before_create { self.class.generate_token(:activation_token) } ?

Comment: You would have it in the `included` block.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ever writing the same method twice, you are right that it's probably a sign of writing bad code. If it were me, I would create an abstract class that is a parent class to both Account and User. Make Account and User inherit from this parent class, and put all of the shared logic in that parent class. Then Account and User will automatically have access to that shared logic.

You will want to look up how to make abstract classes in rails. Once you've made the new parent abstract class, make sure Account and User inherit from the parent class instead of ActiveRecord::Base like so:

```
class Account < NewAbstractClass
end
class user < NewAbstratClass
end
```

I am neither agreeing nor disagreeing with the above or below answers, through using concerns or through using modules. However, this is the way that I have solved this problem before in the past, and this is a good object orient way to try and solve the problem of shared logic between multiple classes.

Comment: It's a good solution when the mother-class of the 2 sub-classes has a reason to exist, i.e. it represents a true concept.

Answer (score 0):

For code reusability, we use modules. The more common usage of modules in Rails is to share common code.
so the answer is

- write the same method in module
- place it in lib like `lib/some_token_generation.rb`

`module SomeTokenGeneration
  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end`

- after that include this module, in which model you want to use
  like `models/some_model1.rb`

`class SomeModel1
  include SomeTokenGeneration
end`

or `models/some_model2.rb`

`class SomeModel2
  include SomeTokenGeneration
end`

The include method adds any methods in the module as instance methods to the class

Let’s look at a scenario where two classes could share an instance method.

So you can use that method in both models as `models/some_model1.rb`

`class SomeModel1
  include SomeTokenGeneration
  def some_method1
     self.generate_token(column)
  end
end`

or `models/some_model2.rb`

`class SomeModel2
  include SomeTokenGeneration
  def some_method2
     self.generate_token(column)
  end
end`

Comment: Your answer was right in Rails < 4. The default library inclusion caused compilation error on complex projects, so `concerns` were implemented in Rails 4, just for avoid to put shareable code into `lib`'s.